# SDK 2.0: Page Tools?

Tags: rally

In SDK 1.0, there was a facility to add "Page Tools" to the app via the appHeader.  Is there a similar capability in SDK 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time there is no similar page tools menu yet in the 2.0 SDK.